# Cloudformation, Template validation error: Invalid template property or properties

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create my first cloudformation template and i'm having some validation errors, which is not really that descriptive or usefull. I'm getting a

> "Template validation error: Invalid template property or properties
>   [PrivateSubnet2RouteTableAssociation, AttachGateway,
>   OutBoundPrivateNetworkAclEntry, PrivateSubnetNetworkAclAssociation3,
>   PrivateSubnetNetworkAclAssociation2,
>   PrivateSubnetNetworkAclAssociation1, PrivateNetworkAcl,
>   PrivateSubnet1RouteTableAssociation, PrivateSubnet1, PrivateSubnet2,
>   PrivateSubnet3, InboundPrivateNetworkAclEntry, PrivateSubnetRoute,
>   SSHSecurityGroup, InternetGateway, S3 Bucket,
>   PrivateSubnet3RouteTableAssociation]"

Is there a way to properly debug the template? or could somone explain to me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks!

https://gist.github.com/mathwro/42625efeab2d2f2043f150d0325da79c

Answer (score 0):

Line 62 at the end of your declaration of your `EC2Instance` you've got an extra `}` that is in essence closing off your `Resources`

Once you've done that, some other errors come up and thats because you need an additional `}` at the end of your cloud formation template to close the whole template off.

And then there is another error... but hopefully this gets you on your way :)

Comment: You also need to change the name of your S3 resource: from `S3 Bucket` to `S3Bucket` (ie remove space) - resource names are alpha numeric only. And the only other error remaining (or at least what's blocking it now) is that you haven't defined the condition: `3AZCondition` :)

Comment: thank you so much for the fast answer. It instantly allowed me to continue and get some proper debug information.

Note to the S3 Bucket, the name need to be all lowercase :)